# tags$strong in titlePanel renders as string <strong> in HTML title

Tags: r, shiny

Well, as my question states, when I use:

```
  titlePanel(tags$strong("My App Title")),
```

It does produce bold title in my shiny app and the HTML page, and no errors appear in the console, but it also displays

```
<strong>My App Title</strong>
```

in the FF and Chrome window title bar and tab titles, and HTML source looks as you would expect:

```
<title>
    <strong>My App Title</strong>
</title>
```

Is this a bug? I can easily change the css file to achieve the same, just wanted to know if this is normal behavior or I messed up something else in the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec [a title element most only contain text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element), it should not contain other HTML elements. This is why you see the literal text "strong" on the tabs and such

The `titlePanel()` function actually does two things. It 1) creates an `<h2>` element with the contents of your title and 2) adds a `<title>` tag in the `<head>`. It's fine for the `<h2>` element to have a `<strong>` child, so you really only need to change what's being sent to the `<title>` tag. It just so happens that `titlePanel()` actually has two parameters so you can specify them independently. Just change your code to

```
titlePanel(tags$strong("My App Title"), "My App Title")
```

Comment: As usual, it serves me well for not reading the docs... :)
It does say clearly:

titlePanel(title, windowTitle = title)

Thanks!